# Google Sheets: IMPORTRANGE on multiple sheets error

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I am using IMPORTRANGE with a query to stack a very large document of over 60k lines. Basically I can pull it from the master sheet with vlookup as its too large. So I am importing it in sections using IMPORTRANGE.

I am using the following to take a one column sheet into another. The original sheet has data is 57234 lines. However this may change as it updates.

```
=query({Importrange("ULS ADDRESS","LINK!b1:b30000");Importrange("URL ADDRESS", "LINK!b30001:b60000")}, "select Col1 where Col1 is not Null", 0)
```

So the issue I face is in the second import with `b60000` that is over the data amount and doesn't pull anything from 30001 onwards. If I put it exactly right it pulls in the data.

I've tried to add the Col1 is not NULL to see if that would fix it but it doesn't work. How to I overshoot the filled cells to future proof this?

Comment: are you saying that the formula works only if second part of the formula is `LINK!b30001:b57234` and fails if its done as `LINK!b30001:b60000`

Comment: Hey :) So if I go b60000 it doesn't pull in any of the second results.  if its b57234 it pulls it all in, but I want to overshoot to capture future additions. Seems to just ignore anything for the second pull of data if I overshoot the last cell.

Comment: Ok. what does happen if & when you use just the single `=query(importrange("URL","LINK!B1:B60000"),"Where Col1 is not null")`

Comment: i get an error 'result too large', this is how i started looking into this as files with a lot of lines cant be imported normally with import range so im trying to stack them.

Comment: Ahh that got me thinking, maybe the second range is too big but because it brings the first values in there is no error shown.  So i added a tried link 40000-60000 and it works! Looking at the very last line in the original there is ERROR on the last line but not flagging in red anywhere with the error reason. So solved!   Thank you for getting me there :)